# About "Request()" of Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Python 3.5.2 and Scrapy 1.1，
I have a question about "Request()":

If using "callback",it can be writen like this:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/article-1.html",callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    title = response.xpath('a/text()').extract()
    link = response.xpath('a/@href').extract()
    desc = response.xpath('text()').extract()
    print title, link, desc
```

Now I dont use "callback",is this right as follow?

```
article = Request(url="http://www.example.com/article-1.html")

# Are these right as follow?
title = article.xpath('a/text()').extract()   
link = article.xpath('a/@href').extract()
desc = article.xpath('text()').extract()
```

Comment: It's not correct. In this case, `article` is just a `Request` object that haven't even been made. If you want to execute that request, you should `yield` it, so that the request object is passed to the scheduler. Then, the response is handled by a proper callback when it has been downloaded.
Note that this works asynchronously.

Comment: Also to add to @stummjr. If you leave the `callback` parameter empty, the callback defaults to the spider's `parse` method.